# Capturing a fleeting error message

Tags: error-handling, screenshot

Sometimes I some program spits out an error message, but it shows it only for a really short moment so that I can't read it, but I can reproduce it easily. Is there some simple way of capturing it e.g. using some screenshot tool and telling it to snap quickly 10 times within the next second, without using some sort of video recording?

Comment: Make a movie with your cell phone. Then review it and tell us what the error was. Provide more details... What version Ubuntu. What program. What versions?

Comment: @heynnema This is not about the specific bug I encountered, it's about a general approach. I'd prefer to not rely on any type of video recording.

Answer (score 1):

```
 sudo apt-get install recordmydesktop
```

will install [recordmydesktop](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/recordmydesktop.1.html) a decade old app to do what you describe.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> starts it and
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>LeftAlt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> stops it

Its Performance tab determines how many frames per second you wish recorded.